# object scope in containers

Tags: c++, vector, constructor, scope

I am trying to put a vector of objects in a class and running into problems with scope. I need to construct each with different parameters. I am trying to avoid empty constructors and an initialization function as that defeats the purpose of having a constructor. I have something like this:

```
class inner
{
    inner::inner(string &dev);
    inner::~inner();
};

class outer
{
    vector<inner> devs;
};
```

This creates an empty vector. I then need to construct the devs vector objects in an outer method. Unfortunately, they are going out of scope and the destructor is being called in the same method. I need the scope to be that of the vector (ie: the outer object) rather than the method that instantiates the vector elements. Here's my construction code:

```
for (unsigned i=0; i<dev_strings.size(); i++)
{
    devs.resize(i+1, inner(dev_strings[i]));
}
```

I guess I could use new to get inner object, but them I have a vector of pointers to objects and will have to delete explicitly, which seems to defeat the purpose of having vector manage memory for it's resources. I would prefer to avoid this.

Comment: The question is extremely unclear. The devs object exists as long as the object of type outer exists. Try to organize your question in a sound way.

Comment: Why do you use resize in such strange manner? Have you tried vector's push_back() method? Even better! If you are using c++11 try emplace_back()